# How to store array values in dictionary?

Tags: asp.net

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '/', '-', '\t', '=', '&', '?' };

string Str = Convert.ToString(entry.Value);

string[] words = Str.Split(delimiterChars);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx

Comment: Explain! Just code is not enough..

Comment: What's going to be the key and what's going to be the value for each entry?

Comment: Please explain, why you need this in a Dictionary.

Comment: I have some 9k urls, I need to keep a count of the most recurring words. I have been able to split the words for the first url, I want to store the words in dictionary so that when the same words are recurring in the following urls the count can be maintained for each word. Also the new words can be added to the dictionary.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. You don´t need to store the chars of the array. You have to loop through your list of urls, split it with your delimiterchar list, and check if the word exists in your dictionary (as key) and the count (as value). your declaration could be: Dictionray<string, int>. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (wrote it the last minutes):

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '/', '-', '\t', '=', '&', '?' };
Dictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string,int>();

List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
urlList.Add("test test test");

foreach (string url in urlList)
{
  var wordList = url.Split(delimiterChars);
  foreach (string word in wordList)
  {
    if (!result.ContainsKey(word))
    {
      result.Add(word, 1);
    }
    else
    {
      result[word]++;
    }
  }
}
Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

and tested.

Comment: Don´t forget the % coding of some chars ....

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array in a dictionary the same as any other type of object:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();

dict.Add(1, new int[] { 1, 2, 3});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an array to a dictionary, you can do this.

```
Dictionary<string, int> wordsDict = words.ToDictionary(x => x, x => 1);
```

This will put the string as the key and set `1` as the default integer (because it has appeared once). However, if your `words` array contains duplicate keys, it'll throw an exception because a dictionary can't contain duplicate keys. Instead of having a convoluted LINQ query to handle that, I suggest using a simple loop.

```
Dictionary<string, int> wordsDict = new Dictionary<string,int>();

foreach (string word in words)
{ 
    if(wordsDict.ContainsKey(word)) //if the word already exists
       wordsDict[word]++; //increment the value by 1
    else
       wordsDict.Add(word, 1); //otherwise add the word to the dictionary
}
```

Comment: Thanks keyboardP, will try this and let you know the result.